# Connecting through AstManProxy using Asterisk.NET

Tags: c#, proxy, asterisk, asteriskami

I am developing an application that uses asterisk server to manage SIP calls.
I am using Asterisk.NET library for this.

I needed to connect the asterisk server through a proxy server AstManProxy. But, when I connect through the proxy, it gives me a TimeOut Exception.

Can Anybody tell me how can I connect through AstManProxy?

Answer (score 0):

First test that you can connect to asterisk WITHOUT proxy.

After that check again you correctly configured proxy.

If all seams ok, use tcpdump or wireshark to see communication between your app and proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure I typically follow if astmanproxy is running on the same machine as Asterisk.

ENABLE AMI ON PORT 5039
vi /etc/asterisk/manager.conf

```
[general]
enabled = yes
port = 5039
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
timestampevents = yes

[username]
secret = password
read = all
write = all
```

THEN ENSURE AMI IS RESPONDING

```
telnet localhost 5039
Action: Command
Command: core show channels<enter><enter>
Action: Logoff <enter><enter>
```

CONFIGURE ASTERISK MANAGER PROXY ON PORT 5038

```
vi /etc/asterisk/astmanproxy.conf
host = localhost, 5039, username, password, on, off
listenport = 5038
```

THEN TEST ON PROXY PORT 5038

```
telnet localhost 5038
Action: Command
Command: core show channels<enter><enter>
Action: Logoff <enter><enter>
```

THEN USE MONIT TO ENSURE ASTMANPROXY STAYS RUNNING
vi /etc/monit/monitrc

```
#Asterisk AMI Manager Proxy Monitoring Rule
check process astmanproxy with pidfile /var/run/astmanproxy.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/astmanproxy start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/astmanproxy stop"
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 5038 then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```